# Почему аккумуляторы следует заряжать от того же вольтажа, который они сами способны дать на максимальном заряде?

Tags: электроника

К примеру, у меня есть 4 последовательно соединенные 18650. Почему я должен заряжать их от 16.8в? Что будет если заряжать от меньшего тока? Что будет если заряжать от большего тока? например 19в?

Comment: В первом случае - нарисуй цепь и посмотри, куда ток пойдёт.

Comment: Вообще-то то, что в вольтах, называется напряжением.

Comment: если вы хотите узнать, как заряжать аккумуляторы, то надо читать на них документацию, там есть графики разные для заряда и разряда и как оно всё зависит от температуры

Comment: и да, наблюдать за тем, что будет если  заряжать током 19в лучше из укрытия

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не по теме сайта.